# Can not save inserted data in to sqlite on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to insert a row in to history table. But it's not working without error.

I can't find the new row in history table.=> It's not saved in to SQLite.

I have a function like that:

```
public void insert(history t) {
        try {
            String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(null, '" + t.getWord() + "', '" + t.getDate() + "', '" + t.getMean() + "')";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
//            db.execSQL(query);
//            db.close();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("word", t.getWord());
            values.put("date", t.getDate());
            values.put("mean", t.getMean());
            long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
// I have 6 rows in table after inserted a row i get size of table = 7(increase +1). 
// After that i try to get size of table in other activity but it's still only 6. I used Explorer in order to see all of data on android but i could not find the new row.

            Toast.makeText(context, "id inserted = " + id + " / size of table =" + getAll().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// Toast show : id inserted =7/ size of table =7
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ex :" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I try all your suggest, but is still not work and return without error.

Can you help me and tell me why? Thanks!!

Logcate:

Comment: Recomendations: surround with try{}catch(SQLiteException e){} and print exception in logcat. Also add db.beginTransaction before execSQL, add db.setTransactionSuccessfull() after execSQL, and then add db.endTransaction(). Try with the "convenience" method db.insert(... instead of db.execSQL(... this method has a return value you could verify to confirm the row was inserted.

Comment: Put your logcat

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I did but it's still not work

Comment: Show the code that calls your `insert`.

Comment: @CL it's above. I have just edited

Comment: Make sure your table name is correct. May be you put some other table. Error log shows unable to open detabase connection. Check username pwd are correct for open database connection

Comment: I use variable TABLE_NAME for all query:  `private static final String TABLE_NAME = "history";` I don't think is not true

Comment: That edit appears to have failed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SQLiteDatabse `insert` method or the  `insertOrThrow` method, unlike the `execSQL` method, these return values.

Instead of :-

```
    public void insert(history t) {
            String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(null, '" + t.getWord() + "', '" + t.getDate() + "', '" + t.getMean() + "')";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL(query);
            db.close();
    }
```

You could use :-

```
public void insert(history t) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("respective_column_name",t.getWord);
        cv.put("respective_column_name",t.getDate());
        cv.put("respective_column_name",t.getMean());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long insertid = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv); // rowid or -1 if not inserted
        db.close();
}
```

This may fix the underlying issue as it uses specific column names and will build a query along the lines of :-

`INSERT INTO your_table (columna, columnb, columnc) VALUES('word','date','mean')`

Comment: I get rowid != -1. But i can not find it in database

Comment: @QuyNguyen then it is probably an issue with how you are determining that the row has not been added. I'd suggest editing your question to show where you try to get the new row and conclude that the new row doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("Messsage", msg);
     values.put("Name", SenderName);
     values.put("GroupName", Groupname);
     db.insert("TableName", null, values);
```